# Need help finding a specific transition matrix with polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I  am not told it is a transition matrix till later and the book never describes a transition matrix, it just tells me to find $A$ from the equation $[w]_{B}=A[w]_{C}$ where $w$ is an arbitrary matrix and $C$ is the standard basis for the vector space of all polynomials of degree two or less.  So $C={1,x,x^2}$ and $B={1,x+1,(x+1)^2}$.

So I said

for C, $w=c_1(1) + c_2(x) + c_3 (x^2)$

for B, $w= (b_1+b_2+b_3) + (b_2+2b_3)x + (b_3)x^2$

Then it would seem to me that

$
  A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 1 & 1\\
   0 & 1 & 2\\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

But I don't think that is right.  I really don't know what steps to take.

It seems that

$[w_1]_B=(b_1$ $b_2$ $b_3)$ and so on, I don't know I feel like I keep thinking in circles and it doesn't make sense.  Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: If there is anything I need to clarify in here please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you got the wrong transformation direction, otherwise it is fine.

Supposing $w=c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2=b_1+b_2(x+1)+b_3(x+1)^2$ (it helps to write explicitly what you are taking as starting point), you can by rewriting the right hand side (as you did) and comparing coefficients of monomials deduce the relations $c_1=b_1+b_2+b_3$, $c_2=b_2+2b_3$ and $c_3=b_3$. These can be written
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}
$$
But I suppose the left hand side is what is called $[w]_C$, so your matrix is not the one asked for. You can inverse the matrix, giving
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1\\0&1&-2\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}
 = 
 \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}
$$
which if you interchange left and right hand sides looks like what was asked for.

A more "direct" approach would be to express $w=c_1+c_2x+c_3x^2$ in terms of powers of $x+1$. For this it is useful to put $y=x+1$, so $x=y-1$, and expand; then identify the $b_i$ with the coefficients of powers of$~y$. This should give you the second equation right away.